# Can no longer post an image with my questions

Tags: support, images

As of yesterday, there is a strange problem when I try to include an image with my tex.sx questions.

- I click on the image icon or hit `ctrl-G`, and I get the upload
  dialog box, but it tells me that my image is too big to upload, **even
  though I haven't selected an image yet.**
- Then, when I click one of the
  several instances of `cancel`, or the X icon at the upper right of
  the dialog box, nothing happens; I have no way to get back to my
  question. I have to close the browser tab and start over.

I would post a screengrab of the situation, but, well, I can't.

What is going on here, and how, if at all, do I fix it? So far I have tried logging out and back in; I haven't been able to think of anything else to try.

## Update

Posted an image of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA4di.jpg).

[image]

## Update 2

The problem occurs in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Didn't work.

Comment: @crmdgn Does this only happen on tex.se or on other stackexchange sites as well?

Comment: @samcarter Others too.

Comment: @crmdgn: Well, it was my first (and only) guess, since I had a similar issue about one year ago, but it vanished after clearing the cache.

Comment: Post (temporarily) a link to a screenshot hosted elsewhere. Once you (hopefully) solve your issue, you can post it back here, directly, for discoverability purposes.

Comment: Sometimes, imgur does not respond and/or goes to maintenance.

Comment: @thiagowfx Good idea. Done.

Comment: According to the screen shot you posted, the image is too large. Try using some compression or scale it down. [![Reason why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE1DC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE1DC.png)

Comment: Reread my original post. That message appears BEFORE I HAVE SELECTED AN IMAGE.

Comment: This just ignores the question.

Comment: Have you tried a) deleting the cookies for imgur, and maybe SE, b) disabling extensions and add-ons, including user scripts, and c) though I'm sure you meant it to be included in the "several instances of `cancel`" have you clicked on the `close` option, which might stop the uploading that it seems to indicate it is trying to do?

Comment: (1) Try to close down *all* instances of Chrome. Do so by accessing the Task Manager (in Windows) and killing *all* related processes. If this doesn't work, (2) try to restart the computer to clear all existing (possibly stuck) processes of Chrome that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem was a certain browser extension: disabling it solves the problem. I have no idea why *that* extension, which has never created problems before, should do so now, but I'll deal with that later.

Behold:

[image]

Thanks to Gypsy Spellweaver for the tip.